# Ongoing issues with erratic idle, stalling, and backfiring

Tags: honda, accord, stall, rough-idle, backfire

I'm experiencing a problem with my 2002 Honda Accord EX 2.3, 4-cylinder. Upon starting, the idle RPM intermittently fluctuates above 1 and drops, and when I drive, it struggles to go beyond 3 RPM, often resulting in stalling. Restarting is possible, but the idle drops, leading to an immediate stop. Accelerating causes backfiring and eventual halting.
Initially, the issue also included starting problems, with the car refusing to start when it stalls but then would start after waiting for about 30 minutes. Despite changing the fuel pump and distributor, the problem still persists.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about your fuel filter? Considering the issues you're stating, this seems like a logical place to look next (maybe even first). You can pull the one you have and see if you can blow air through it to check it.

Comment: its a 2002 Honda accord, I'm assuming the fuel filter is in the fuel pump unit, in changing the fuel pump what you recommended was done.

Comment: saw this youtube video on line for a 2000 honda accord v6 that stalls and stutters, would appreciate some recommendation on if this could also be whats happening to mine see the URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alpB00hO3WU

Comment: thanks a lot paulster2, truly appreciate your recommendation
so i ran a scan on the car and got the following error codes 
P1166 - HO2S (B2)(S1) HEATER
P1381 - CMP SENSOR INTERMITTENT INTERRUPTION
P1259 - VTEC SYSTEM FAILURE
P0325 - KNOCK SENSOR CIRCUIT
P1167 - H02S S1 HEATER FAILURE
P1399 - MISFIRE IN ANY CYLINDER

Comment: @iamdeed - Ask the mechanic if the fuel filter was changed at the time of pump replacement. "HO2S" is the O2 sensor. Check your O2 fuses under hood. VTEC and knock sensor is not good. Could be electrical or mechanical. If you don't push your engine above 4k RPM, you'll never reach VTEC, so may not be an issue.